# Finding the mean of $X_t = \int_0^t sW_sdW_s$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

For the stochastic integral, where $W_t$ is a Wiener process, I am trying to find the mean of $X_t = \int_0^t sW_sdW_s$. I have read before that any stochastic integral with $dWt$ has mean zero, but I dont know if it extends to cases where I have a random variable in the integrand as well. My approach is to decompose the integral $X_t$ into:

$$
\int_0^t sW_sdW_s = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}t_jW_{t_i}(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i})
$$

Then,

$$
E\left(\int_0^t sW_sdW_s\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}E\left(t_jW_{t_i}(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i})\right)
$$

I believe that I can separate the terms in the expectation into:

$$
E\left(t_jW_{t_i}(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i})\right) = E\left(t_jW_{t_i}\right)E\left(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i}\right)
$$

I am not sure how to find $E\left(t_jW_{t_i}\right)$, although I know it is finite so it doesn't matter because $E\left(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i}\right) = 0$

Comment: Once the integrand is adapted, the expectation is zero.

Comment: Also you simply have $E[t_jW_{t_i}] = t_jE[W_{t_i}] = 0  $